# motion layout programmatically

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

This is my first question on this platform, I am making a part of an app where I need to dynamically move text views with motion layout, but when I add my `showBubble ()` method this when executing the app does not show the text view, there is something I miss?
I think there is some error in the XML when detecting the id of the BubbleUi, but at the end of the day, it may be easier than it seems, you know :(

note: I am translating this text, sorry if there is any mistake in the writing

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"

        motion:duration="3500"
        >
        <OnClick
            motion:targetId="@+id/Bubble"
            motion:clickAction="toggle"
            />

    </Transition>


    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">

    <Constraint
        android:id="@id/Bubble"

        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"

        motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

        >
        <CustomAttribute
            motion:attributeName="backgroundColor"
            motion:customColorValue="@color/colorGreenLight"
            />

    </Constraint>


    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/Bubble"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"

            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            >
            <CustomAttribute
                motion:attributeName="backgroundColor"
                motion:customColorValue="@color/colorGreenLight"
                />

        </Constraint>


    </ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```

java:

```
private void ShowBubble(String tempWord) {
        //Create Motion layout.
        MotionLayout motionBubble = new MotionLayout(ActivityGame.this);
        motionBubble.setId(View.generateViewId());
        motionBubble.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearParams= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        linearParams.setMargins(5,0,5,0);
        motionBubble.setLayoutParams(linearParams);

        //Create the Bubble.
        TextView BubbleUi = new TextView(ActivityGame.this);
        BubbleUi.setId(R.id.Bubble);

        BubbleUi.setText(tempWord);
        BubbleUi.setTextSize(24);
        BubbleUi.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorDefaultWhite));
        BubbleUi.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGreenLight));
        BubbleUi.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        BubbleUi.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        motionBubble.addView(BubbleUi,0);

        ConstraintSet constraintSetBubble = new ConstraintSet();
        constraintSetBubble.clone(motionBubble);

        constraintSetBubble.connect(BubbleUi.getId(),ConstraintSet.TOP,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.TOP);
        constraintSetBubble.connect(BubbleUi.getId(),ConstraintSet.START,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.START);
        constraintSetBubble.connect(BubbleUi.getId(),ConstraintSet.END,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.END);

        constraintSetBubble.applyTo(motionBubble);

        //set transition.

        motionBubble.loadLayoutDescription(R.xml.scene_bubbles);
        linearLayoutBubbles.addView(motionBubble,indiceBubble);

        CurrentMotionBubbleCycle [indiceBubble] = motionBubble;

        motionBubble.transitionToStart();
        motionBubble.transitionToEnd();
    }
```

Comment: when I add the motionBubble.loadlayoutDescription (R.xml.scene_bubbles) the text views are not visible, if I remove the same the text views appear but are not animated